# access SASS values ($colors from variables.scss) in Typescript (Angular2 ionic2)

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, ionic2

In Ionic 2, I would like to access the `$colors` variables from the file "[my project]\src\theme\variables.scss".

This file contains:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  favorite:   #69BB7B
);
```

In a component, I draw a canvas. It looks like that:

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-graph',
})
@View({
    template: `<canvas #myGraph class='myGraph'
     [attr.width]='_size'
     [attr.height]='_size'></canvas>`,
})

export class MyGraphDiagram {
    private _size: number;

    // get the element with the #myGraph on it
    @ViewChild("myGraph") myGraph: ElementRef; 

    constructor(){
        this._size = 150;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() { // wait for the view to init before using the element

      let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.myGraph.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
      // HERE THE COLOR IS DEFINED AND I D LIKE TO ACCESS variable.scss TO DO THAT
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 150);
    }

}
```

As one can see, at some point in this code the color of the shape is defined:          `context.fillStyle = 'blue'` , I would like to use instead something like `context.fillStyle = '[variables.scss OBJECT].$colors.primary '`.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: If you use CSS variables (custom properties), you can grab them easily using `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: [This](https://mattferderer.com/use-sass-variables-in-typescript-and-javascript) seems to be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to access SASS variable directly from typescript/javascript code. However, we can make a workaround to access those variables.

Let me describe briefly the steps to access SASS variables from within typescript source code:

### 1. Creating a SASS Helper Component

Create ***../providers/sass-helper/sass-helper.component.scss***:

```
$prefix: "--"; //Prefix string for custom CSS properties

//Merges a variable name with $prefix
@function custom-property-name($name) {
    @return $prefix + $name;
}

// Defines a custom property
@mixin define-custom-property($name, $value) {
    #{custom-property-name($name)}: $value;
}

body {
    // Append pre-defined colors in $colors:
    @each $name, $value in $colors {
        @include define-custom-property($name, $value);
    }

    // Append SASS variables which are desired to be accesible:
    @include define-custom-property('background-color', $background-color);
}
```

In this SCSS file, we simply create custom properties inside the **body** section of the DOM. You should add each SASS variable that you want to be accessible into this SCSS file by using the **mixin** called `define-custom-property` which expects two parameters: variable name and variable value.

As an example, I have added entries for all the **colors** defined in `$colors` as well as an entry for the SASS variable `$background-color` defined in my ***theme/variables.scss*** file. You can add as many variables as you wish.

Create ***../providers/sass-helper/sass-helper.component.ts***:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export const PREFIX = '--';

@Component({
    selector: 'sass-helper',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class SassHelperComponent {

    constructor() {

    }

    // Read the custom property of body section with given name:
    readProperty(name: string): string {
        let bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
        return bodyStyles.getPropertyValue(PREFIX + name);
    }
}
```

---

### 2. Integrating SASS Helper Component

From now on, we can follow standard **Ionic2** framework principles for component integration and usage.

- Add the component class name (**SassHelperComponent**) into the declarations section of your **NgModule** in ***app.module.ts***
- Insert the following HTML code into the HTML template of your page from where you want to access those magic variables:

  `<sass-helper></sass-helper>`

---

### 3. Using Helper Component

In your page's TS file, you should insert the following lines into your page class:

```
@ViewChild(SassHelperComponent)
private sassHelper: SassHelperComponent;
```

Finally, you can read the value of any SASS variable by just calling the child class method as follows:

```
// Read $background-color:
this.sassHelper.readProperty('background-color');

// Read primary:
this.sassHelper.readProperty('primary');
```

Comment: Yes, but there's got to be an easier way.

Comment: Yeah, I wish there was an easier way but remember SASS must be compiled to CSS therefore, all the variable definitions get lost after compilation. Accessing SASS files directly from typescript code would be an alternative method, however, it requires parsing and HTTP access, which is another trouble.

Comment: Did not have time to try it yet (priority shifting), but since it has already two votes up, It seems validated by other users. Thanks for your help @Mete Cantimur. I know I'll use your input at some point.

Comment: @Mete Cantimur , I finaly implemented it and it works. Thanks (upvote given on top of validation). The only slightly different think I did was renaming "sass-helper.component.ts" and "sass-helper.component.scss" to "sass-helper.ts" and "sass-helper.scss" . Before doing that the colors were not in the `body` of the CSS when controlling in the Chrome console.

Comment: Wow, I wish I could upvote this 100 times! Very clever solution!

Comment: I followed everything exactly. Mine's not saving the colors in body. When I tried selecting properties set by bootstrap, it works though.

Comment: For those copy/pasting and it isn't saving to the body - the op forgot to include styleUrls: ['./sass-helper.component.scss'] in the @Component declaration.  If that's not included, the scss never runs, and stuff doesn't get added to the body - ergo, blank variables when reading them in javascript.

Comment: doesn't work with current angular version, while the style elements are injected in the body into one of the many style tags, they attributes are not present in the `window.getComputedStyle(document.body);`

Comment: Seeing the same issue as @AbhinavAtul on Angular 15. Is this working for anyone else? Is there a way to make this work.

Answer (score 16):

One possibility is to **generate** a `.ts` file from the `.scss` file. A simple example of this process:

1. Install `npm i --save-dev @crocsx/scss-to-json`. Note: Previously I had `scss-to-json` here, but since this is not maintained I updated to the fork.
2. Put this in your `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "scss2json": "echo \"export const SCSS_VARS = \" > src/app/scss-variables.generated.ts && scss-to-json src/variables.scss >> src/app/scss-variables.generated.ts"
  },
```

and run it with `npm run scss2json`. Windows users will need to adjust the example.

3. Access the variables:

```
    import {SCSS_VARS} from './scss-variables.generated';
    ...
    console.log(SCSS_VARS['$color-primary-1']);
```

One advantage of this is, that you'll get type completion from IDE's and it's a quite simple means to achieve your goal in general.

Of course you could make this more advanced, for example by making the generated file read only and by putting the script into it's own `.js` file and make it work on every OS.

Comment: It works very well, at least with a little development. https://gist.github.com/alberto-chiesa/b21500885a22586767a36a7e8f10beb6

Comment: just a side note, this plugin doesn't support maps

Comment: scss-to-json seems no longer maintained

Comment: I guess you noticed because it causes problems when upgrading mac to ventura? We're now using a fork, I'll update the snippets to reflect that.

Answer (score 12):

This is possible using CSS Modules.

### CSS Modules

From the project [description](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules):

> When importing the CSS Module from a JS Module, it exports an object with all mappings from local names to global names.

In a way that we could read variables from css/scss file like this:

```
import styles from "./style.css";    

element.innerHTML = '<div class="' + styles.className + '">';
```

Support for CSS Modules is already setup by default by the Angular CLI which uses Webpack configured with the [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/).

The steps to make it work are:

1. Export only the scss variables that you want to use.
2. Configure a typescript module for `styles.scss`.
3. Import the variables in your typescript components.

### 1 - Export the variables

In your `styles.scss`, use the keyword [`:export`](https://github.com/css-modules/icss#export) to export $colors. It seems that `:export` doesn't support exporting maps, only strings, so we have to create a mixin to convert a map into strings:

```
$colors: (
  primary: #387ef5,
  secondary: #32db64,
  danger: #f53d3d,
  light: #f4f4f4,
  dark: #222,
  favorite: #69bb7b,
);

@mixin rule($key, $value, $prefix) {
  #{$prefix}-#{$key}: $value;
}
@mixin map-to-string($map, $prefix) {
  @each $key, $value in $map {
    @include rule($key, $value, $prefix);
  }
}

:export {  
  @include map-to-string($colors, "colors");
}
```

The generated `:export` will be:

```
:export {
  "colors-danger": "#f53d3d";
  "colors-dark": "#222";
  "colors-favorite": "#69bb7b";
  "colors-light": "#f4f4f4";
  "colors-primary": "#387ef5";
  "colors-secondary": "#32db64";
}
```

### 2 - Configure a typescript module for `styles.scss`

We have to create a `styles.scss.d.ts` file with the following content to allow the import of `styles.scss` in our typescript files:

```
export interface globalScss {}

export const styles: globalScss;

export default styles;
```

### 3 - Import the variables in the target typescript component

As we used a default export, we could import it in our component like this:

```
//...
import styles from 'src/styles.scss';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-colors-use',
  templateUrl: './colors-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./colors-user.component.scss'],
})
export class ColorsUserComponent implements OnInit {

  buttonColor = styles["colors-primary"] //"#387ef5"
```

### 4 - (Plus) Add type definition to `styles.scss.d.ts`

You could add type information to `style.scss.d.ts`:

```
export interface globalScss {  
  "colors-danger": string
  "colors-dark": string
  "colors-favorite": string
  "colors-light": string
  /**
   * Used for app-button, usually blue
   */
  "colors-primary": string
  /**
   * Used for borders, usually green
   */
  "colors-secondary": string
}

export const styles: globalScss;

export default styles;
```

In that way, you could have some benefits in an editor like VS code:

[image: Comments]

[image: Auto complete]

UPDATE:

The configuration above only works until ng 10. Css Modules configuration has changed considerably from ng 10 to ng 11.

Comment: It maybe be helpful to point out that the export has to happen in a global scss file, as Angular only uses the Webpack css-loader, which parses the export, for global styles.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to make it work. All I get back when I import the module is an empty object (`{}`). I have the exact same content from the post. Did anything change since in this setup?

Comment: @ReneHamburger I can't get this to work either. Literally copied the steps line for line. In my component where I try to `import styles from '../../styles.scss';` it causes an error `"export 'default' (imported as 'styles') was not found in '../../styles.scss'`

Comment: Which angular version are you using ?

Comment: @tiagolisalves 11.0.5

Comment: Maybe something have changed on it. I remember using angular 9 or 10 on this answer. I will try to update it to ng 11.

Comment: @tiagolisalves that would be super appreciated. I'm trying to translate a project from Vue to Angular and in Vue I used CSS Modules in this exact way. Strangely, I am getting different behaviour on StackBlitz compared to locally on my IDE. On SB the module loads, `console.log(styles)` gives `:export{colors-primary:#387ef5;colors-secondary:#32db64;colors-danger:#f53d3d;colors-light:#f4f4f4;colors-dark:#222;colors-favorite:#69bb7b}` but `console.log(styles["colors-primary"])` is `undefined`

Comment: Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-to-angular-translation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanimation-section%2Fanimation-section.component.ts

Comment: @ChrisA @Hicaro Css modules configuration changed considerably from ng 10 to ng 11. Now, its not the default. You have to set `modules : true` on the webpack configuration, which is not enabled on ng 11. I think its the case to create an issue on the @angular/cli repo to ask for expose the configuration of it.

Comment: OK thanks @tiagolisalves . It seems for now my best option is to downgrade to 10 while I wait for any issue to be resolved. I have created https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19667 , we will see what happens :)

Comment: I saw it. Great contribution. I won’t have a compromise on it, but I will try to come up with a solution as a PR.

Comment: Was marked as a duplicate of an already closed issue. Looks like this is not something they want to support going forward :( https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19622

Comment: ChrisA @tiagolisalves thanks for getting a resolution on this. It seems the Angular team will not do anything about it.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add up something to @mete-cantimur answer.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

const PREFIX = '--';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-styles-helper',
  templateUrl: './styles-helper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./styles-helper.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class StylesHelperComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  readProperty(name: string): string {
    const bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
    return bodyStyles.getPropertyValue(PREFIX + name);
  }
}
```

My helper component wasn't being able to modify body styles. Even I set up everything correctly, custom properties were not being saved.

I had to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the component in order to let it modify body styles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't work for me. In the `body` there are still no styles. Also you are not using `sassHelper` ...

Comment: @testing I renamed sassHelper into StylesHelperComponent. You can name it anything :). Try saving some custom property from styles.scss and see if it saves. You can check from DevTools > Elements > Computer Styles. If it appears there, then your issue is definitely related to view encapsulation.

Comment: Instead of creating separate files I now used `ng gc SassHelper`. After importing the stylesheet and including your tip it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Is this whole component-style-helper approach used for obtaining styles that are already applied somewhere in the DOM?  I want to be able to read scss variables that aren't necessary used anywhere... so I'm guessing this approach won't work, correct?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is now a few years old, but I thought I'd share the solution I use. It is a more simplistic version of @mete-cantimur's answer, there is no requirement to set up any extra CSS style sheets. It will read from the loaded styles on the page instead.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[css-helper]',
})
export class CssHelperDirective {

    element: any;

    constructor(_ref: ElementRef) {
        this.element = _ref.nativeElement;
    }

    readProperty(name: string): string {
        return window.getComputedStyle(this.element).getPropertyValue(name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div #primary css-helper class="primary"></div>
```

```
@ViewChild('primary', {read: CssHelperDirective})
private cssHelper: CssHelperDirective;
```

```
let color = this.cssHelper.readProperty('background-color');
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to share variables between SASS and Typescript files.

First, declare the variables.

```scss
// Screen Sizes
$screen-tablet1: 768px;
$screen-tablet2: 800px;
$screen-tablet3: 1240px;
```

In the `styles.scss`, read the variables and declare CSS custom properties to be used globally.

```scss
// import the declared variables
:root {
  --screen-tablet1: #{$screen-tablet1};
  --screen-tablet2: #{$screen-tablet2};
  --screen-tablet3: #{$screen-tablet3};
}
```

For example, I want to update the number of grid columns according to the screen width.

```js
getGridCols(width: number) {
    const sizeTablet1 = parseInt(
      window
        .getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
        .getPropertyValue('--screen-tablet1')
        .replace('px', '')
    );

    const sizeTablet3 = parseInt(
      window
        .getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
        .getPropertyValue('--screen-tablet3')
        .replace('px', '')
    );
    if (width < sizeTablet1) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (width < sizeTablet3) {
      return 2;
    }
    return 3;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, I used the following taken from Bersling's answer.

```
npm i --save-dev ruoqianfengshao/scss-to-json

npm i --save-dev node-sass

"scripts": {
...
    "scss2json": "echo export const SCSS_VARS =  > .\\src\\app\\scss-variables.generated.ts && scss-to-json .\\src\\app\\_variables.scss >> .\\src\\app\\scss-variables.generated.ts"
}

npm run scss2json

import {SCSS_VARS} from './scss-variables.generated';
...
console.log(SCSS_VARS['$color-primary-1']);
```