# Ionic - custom colors from SASS file in ngStyle

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, colors, sass

In my Ionic project, in my `src/theme/variables.scss`, below the `$colors` group, I have another group of colors `$buttonColors` which looks like this:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);
$buttonColors: (
  sampleRed: #A92A0E,
  sampleBlue:  #162C60
);
```

In my .css file I can use the second group of colors like this:

```
.element {
  color: color($buttonColors, sampleRed, base);
}
```

But if I want to use the code from above in `[ngStyle]="{'color' : 'color($buttonColors, sampleRed, base)'}"` - this would not work.

And in my case I want to use this color specifically in ngStyle. How can I reference to this color correctly in `ngStyle`?

Comment: You cant access sass variables from code since its pre-compile and it turns into plain css. There are work arounds to achieve such things, But in my opinion its not wroth it. If you still want to, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2

Comment: @dAxx_ I noticed that the topic you sent me was regarding the .ts file. However, I want to access that variable in my .html file in `[ngStyle]` of an element. Is this also impossiblel?

Comment: As mentioned you cannot access the sass vars after the app is compiled. Since [ngStyle] is dynamic it will try to fetch the variables AFTER the app is compiled. you can hardcode the value right into the template, or create a reference in your typescript and use that.

Comment: See this issue at Angular's repository [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1253], one of the solutions there is to use sass-vars-loader (https://github.com/epegzz/sass-vars-loader) to compile sass to TS and then include it in the component. Seems a bit messy, but if you really need this feature this can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In component file:

```
import {Sanitizer} from '@angular/core';

export class MyCass {
      sanitizer: Sanitizer;
      myColor = '#444444';

constructor(_sanitizer: Sanitizer) {
        this.sanitizer = _sanitizer;
    }
```

In the Html file:

```
<ion-title [attr.style]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('--color: ' + myColor)"></ion-title>
```

It worked for me.
But you have to use ionic 4 CSS variables.