# Update Sass Variables ($variable ) from Type Script

Tags: css, angular, sass

Is there any way I can set my color variables ($background-color,$secondary-color) depending on what is configured in database against each user?

I have used custom properties like below.

```
:root {
  --UserBackgrouncolor: #008cba;
}
```

But , `background-color: darken(#008cba, 0%)` is not working with custom property i.e

```
background-color: darken(var(--UserBackgrouncolor), 0%)
```

I can update custom property `--UserBackgrouncolor` from app.component.ts (angular 5) but cannot update SCSS variables (`$background-color,$secondary-color`) dynamically form app.component.ts

Comment: it may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2