# How change the value of the variable Sass in Angular 4?

Tags: css, angular, sass

The variable `$color = 'red'` is in the file **app.component.scss**
How to get access to this variable $color from the file app.component.ts to change its value to 'green' ?

Comment: There is no direct way but there is a workaround [**Check this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353709/3937794)

Comment: If you want to change styles dynamically you can use `[ngClass]` in your template to add different class conditionally but you do need to have all the style classes separately in your scss file.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. Sass is translated to pure css on compile time, at run time there is no sass and its variables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that you should have 2 variables

```
$color-red = 'red' ;
$color-green = 'green'
```

and then define 2 classes

```
.color-red{
   color: $color-red;
}

.color-green{
   color: $color-green;
}
```

and then as Sourav said use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to apply classes conditonally