# Refer SCSS variable value in HTML or TS file in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

I was doing the research if it is possible to use the SCSS variable value in HTML or TS in Angular.

For example

I have a variable called `$mdBreakpoint: 992px;` inside **_variable.scss** file

In html I have a condition

`[ngClass]="{'col-sm-3': innerWidth >= 992}"`

**992** is the same value as the `$mdBreakpoint`

My question is it possible to refer `$mdBreakpoint`in HTML condition.

I am using Angular 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access SASS values ($colors from variables.scss) in Typescript (Angular2 ionic2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable which holds value of `mdBreakpoint` and then use it HTML template:

TypeScript:

```
mdBreakpoint = 992;
```

HTML:

```
[ngClass]="{'col-sm-3': innerWidth >= mdBreakpoint }"
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems that there is no way to access SASS now, but if you want to have a something like global variable, then you can create your variable in `environment.ts` file and use in any component:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  MD_BREAKPOINT: 992 
};
```

and in your component:

```
export class YourComponent {  
  title = 'myapp works!';
  mdBreakpoint = environment.MD_BREAKPOINT;
}
```

Comment: This one I already know....... This is not what I am looking for. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @SanJaisy please, see my updated answer and maybe it is useful to you.

Comment: Since I already have a variable defined in SCSS file. I am not looking for  ways to create constant file and use it. I am trying to consume from the SCSS variable only

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly supported by Angular, html or sass. You can't access scss variables in a html template without writing some logic.

See this answer if you want more information on how to do it: [access SASS values ($colors from variables.scss) in Typescript (Angular2 ionic2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353709/5701521)