# Get CSS Parameter from Typescript Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, angular8

Is there a way to **Get** a variable that is set in the global scss file from a ts file in Angular (8)
I'm looking to use some of the defined variables dynamically in a canvas element defined in the ts code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a way to do this using a styles service based on 
https://en.programqa.com/question/52907585/

---

Within Global.SCSS

```
@mixin ExportVariables($map, $prefix: null) {
  $mapPrefix: "--#{$prefix}";

  @if ($prefix){
    $mapPrefix: "#{$mapPrefix}-";
  }

  body {
    @each $name, $value in $map {
      #{$mapPrefix}#{$name}: $value;
    }
  }
}

--idle-state: #29ABE2;

// Import each of these in the theme service
$stateSCSS:(
  idle: var(--idle-state),
);
@include ExportVariables($stateSCSS, 'stateSCSS');
```

In the Service

```
const bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);

this.stateSCSS = {
  idle: bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--stateSCSS-idle'),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers your questions:  [access SASS values ($colors from variables.scss) in Typescript (Angular2 ionic2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2)

TLDR:

> Unfortunately, there is no way to access SASS variable directly from typescript/javascript code. However, we can make a workaround to access those variables.

You can view the workaround in the post mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to do this without using SASS, you can try this:

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(--your-variable)
```