# Why does not work import CSS in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have tried to import scss styles in `.ts` file:

```
import style from "./map.scss";
```

This file contains:

```
.Map {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I get message:

> map.scss"' has no default export.

I want to use this CSS properties in Ts like:

```
DOMFunction.createElement("div",{ id: "map", class: style.Map });
```

Where `style.Map` is property that I need

Comment: You can't import SCSS styles in TS files because SCSS is not TS/JS code.

Comment: If to write additional file: `map.scss.d.ts` I can

Comment: Just do => import  "./map.scss";

Comment: One comment DOMFunction.createElement("div",{ id: "map"); and style as #map{
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
} it will automatically add id map css to it

Comment: if you need to add a class .Map {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
} then let element = DOMFunction.createElement("div",{ id: "map"}) and then element.classList.add("Map");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import `.scss` file, then you should include it in global style sheet:

**styles.scss:**

```
@import url('./map.scss');
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to access SASS values ($colors from variables.scss) in Typescript, then [you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2)

As an alternative, you can set style by your own using `ngStyle`:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'width': 'calc(100% - ' + yourVariable + 'px)' }"></div>
```

Comment: Import inside ts? I need to get CSS properties as variable in ts file