# How to access scss variables in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I wanted to generate an object and it will create an HTML element. Here I need to supply color, background-color, border to that object.

Instead of hard coding all those values, I wanted to grab them from SCSS.

I tried this way and it works. Not sure it is the correct way to do or not. So, looking for perfect solution

SCSS sample code:

```
:root {
    --normal-rate: #00008b;
    --special-rate : #80d4ff;
    --flat-rate : #F7941D;
}
```

Typescript Code:

```
this.normalRate = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--normal-rate");
this.specialRate = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(RateColor.SpecialRate);
this.flatRate = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(RateColor.FlatRate);

this.obj= [
        { title: '', allDay: false,..., backgroundColor: this.specialRate, borderColor: this.specialRate },
        { title: '', allDay: false,..., backgroundColor: this.normalRate, borderColor: this.normalRate },
        { title: '', allDay: false,..., backgroundColor: this.flatRate, borderColor: this.flatRate }
      ];
```

Comment: I have always wondered this but I think your way is good too. I have stumbled upon other implementations (https://mattferderer.com/use-sass-variables-in-typescript-and-javascript), one was importing the SCSS variables as a JSON Object using an npm package. As far as to which is the best way, not sure. But I think I am going to try your way.

Comment: @AliF50  tried from that link but unable to import scss file.. and also, I dont use webpack in my project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2 , check that out too. Most of them are more complicated than your way. My only concern with your way is that does it pollute the global namespace?

Comment: Is very hard to define a solution as the best or recommended, it depends on your website structure. This one is ok. Another way of doing this is to create a CSS class that sets those properties to these variables and to set that class to your new component. Also note that those aren't SASS variables, they are CSS variables. here https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables you can read about the difference between them and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties about CSS variables.

Comment: @alexortizl Since we can't access SASS in typescript I used CSS variables to grab and make it dynamic

Comment: @AliF50 I tried that way but my project don't have webpack setup. and also it didn't worked for me

Comment: Gorgeous way of painlessly getting a CSS variable. Tested and worked in Angular 12 with TypeScript 4.3.