# How to check scss variables in Angular 11 tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, sass

My components use scss for styles. I want to check that the background color (stored in a scss variable) is correct.

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2#answer-63429103) answer but I have Angular 11

Comment: Your unit tests are comparing against compiled output via headless browser etc. As in the question you linked the version of angular is irrelevant here unfortunately. So checking your scss file vars isn't happening unless you want to go make some custom stuff to do so. You can however check the output in the same way though against like `nativeElement.getComputedStyle()`, are you talking about something like that?

Comment: Yes, but the css file says ```background-color: $ThBackgroundColorBg;```, not ```background-color: #fff;``` I need to get value of $ThBackgroundColorBg in test file