# how to override Angular library scss variables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, styling

I created a library in Angular 12 and I have implemented several components, I wanted to standardize the styling colors so I also implemented scss variables, I have created a SCSS file:

```
lib\dinotable.scss
$primary-color: green;
$secondary-color: red;
```

But I also want the library consumers to be able to override the colors in their consuming applications, how can I let them override the variables inside dinotable.scss?

you can find the library here:
https://github.com/chr1soscl/dinolib, use "npm run pack-dt" to build and pack the library, the consumer application is here: https://github.com/chr1soscl/dinolib-consumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to make a seperate SCSS file, maybe called overrides.scss, where the consumers can override the variables themselves. However, you need to make sure that the override styles imported **after** the default Angular SCSS.
This means, you'll maybe have something like:

```
lib\global-variables.scss

$primary-color: green;
$secondary-color: red;

@import 'overrides.scss'
```

Note: SASS are deprecating the @import feature and changes it to @use instead in the future.

Comment: Hi Christian, first thank you for your replay, but I still don't quite get it, globla-variables is a scss file under my lib folder,  so the root folder for the library, the variables are inside the global-variables file, even if I create a overrides.scss file and import it inside global-variables, how would the library consumers gain access to overrides.scss so they can replace the variables with their own colors?

Comment: If you make sure to import your overrides.scss file below all predefined variables, the variables you/the consumer change in your overrides.scss file will override the predefined variables since CSS is cascading. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Hi Christian, I created an overrides.scss file in my library and imported it to goblal-variables.scss at the end of the file like above, I build my library to a npm package, then I installed it to my consumer project, I created another overrides.scss file (in consumer project)and add it to my angular.json style list, even if I make changes there, the package colors are not getting overriden :(, am I doing something wrong? missing some step?

Comment: Hello @ChrisoLopez, did you find a solution ? I am stuck with the same problem

Comment: @CommonPeople I was not able to override the colors when I set them explicitly in the library components, so instead I removed any color setting in the css of the library, instead I am replacing the colors with the bootstrap scss color variables override in the consuming project.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still encountering this, part of the reason we couldn't overwrite the variable scss in the library -> it's compiled

Instead we used css variables (make sure it's unique)

```
:root{
    --base-brand-600: black;
    --base-base-0: #FFFFFF;
    
}

$btn-bg: var(--base-brand-600);
$btn-color: var(--base-base-0);
```

For any client Angular app

```
:root{
    --base-brand-600: blue !important;
    --base-base-0: pink !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest trying to set the variables in the TS file instead, and let the end user override it in general configuration.
Take a look at this:
[access SASS values ($colors from variables.scss) in Typescript (Angular2 ionic2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2)

Comment: I don't want to get access from the typescript, I just want to let the user override them like when you override scss variables for bootstrap.