# Access bootstrap breakpoints from component class

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I noticed there is an `xxl` breakpoint in bootstrap. I need to compare screen width with this value in component class and am looking for a way how to import it and from where, but without success.

I know `Breakpoints` from `@angular/cdk/layout`, but this is not sufficient for me as the largest breakpoint it provides is only `xl`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418804/access-sass-values-colors-from-variables-scss-in-typescript-angular2-ionic2) will help you? It seems not to be that easy to access those values defined in `_variables.scss`. What is the reason that you need it to be that dynamic and not just using `1400px` as a direct value?

Comment: @Tommy Yes, the question seems interesting. And to your question, in case values from external library, I always like rather to reference those values than to hard-code them.